# Using a Client and Server secret to double salt a hash

Tags: cryptography, hash, salt

I want to log IP addresses visiting my site, for aggregated statistics only and to see if the same IP address has visited twice. But I don't want to expose them.

My Idea is in my database.

```
$IP_Verifier = hash($IP + $CONST_Server_salt + $CONST_Client_salt)
```

Where:

- `$CONST_Server_salt` is a hardcoded value in my application code
- `$CONST_Client_salt` is some client-machine specific secret like a machine ID or a random high entropy string they keep in a file locally.

The idea is I want to be able to check the same IP has arrived more than once, so I do want a constant salting, not salt-per-password. However, I can split the salt between the server and the client for added security. And this way if someone asks "What's the verifier for this Big Company IP", they cannot know it without also knowing the client's secret.

- Is this a standard approach?
- Is it unsafe to use const values here?

Comment: @Polygorial Is saving the hash of IP okay though? Or hash of a richer fingerprint?

Comment: @Polygorial "It's considered personal identifiable information according to GDPR". Do you have any source for that claim? As far as I'm aware IP addresses are only PII under very specific circumstances (see C‑582/14 Breyer against Germany) which are not going to apply to a normal website provider. I'd be surprised if that had changed since I last had instruction on this, but nothing's impossible I guess.

Answer (score 7):

Such approach is not reliable.

1. The IP can change. Depending on provider it can change weekly, daily, or even more often.
2. Many users can have the same IP, e.g. in case they are behind a proxy.
3. Client data should not be trusted. There is no guarantee that user does not change client salt.

I'd suggest you to use some kind of fingerprinting. Then you will be able to distinguish users with high probability. There is no 100% guarantee. But the probability will be higher than in the case of relying on IPs only.

I'd suggest not to use any client salt.

Also server salt makes not much sense, if this salt is used for all IPs or for all fingerprints. You should assume that the attacker obtained the salt. In such case brute-forcing hashes with or without salt will take the same time.

Comment: the server constant salt is a compromise; it ensures a lookup table attack cannot happen with pre-calculated hashes; the attacker needs to perform `hash(salt + targetIP)` themselves first which slows down lookup if they have a lot of target IPs to check. I think it should slow them down as much as regular per-password salting (well it gets faster proportional to the average number of times an IP appears in the log, which I expect to be low compared to the number of unique ips), it just means that the same IP gets hashed to the same verifier_ID every time so I can tally visits more easily.

Comment: 1./2. Point of fingerprinting rather than just IP is sensible, just trying to manage GDPR which is why I don't want to save any identifiable data, only hashes

Comment: 3. Untrusted client data I don't think it matters, it will mess up my stats if everyone spoofs their salt, but is that a good trade-off against the added security for the users who are being truthful about their client salt? Their data is surely better protected? A client can probably spoof any fingerprint data

Comment: To brute-forcing: A single GPU can compute 100 Megahashes per second. Means, if you use SHA-256 or other quick hash algorithm, to brute-force *all* possible IPs of type IPv4 (2^32 ~= 4*10^9) such single GPU would need just 40 seconds.

Comment: Fingerprints do not contain data that identify person. Just knowing display resolution or the list of fonts available in the system does not identify the person. Only IP can point to a small set of persons or in some cases to a single person. Thus if you collect fingerprints, you don't identify the person. But you can tell if this is the same person or actually the same device.

Comment: Preventing fingerprinting will require much more efforts than manipulating your salt. Also some anti-fingerprinting measures have negative usability consequences, like sticking to some fixed browser window size or using only particular set of fonts. That's why there will be not many users who will really do that.

Comment: Brute forcing; I'd intend to use a slow hashing algorithm since I only need to hash once when the ip/fingerprint is logged and the tally is incremented. So your brute force example doesn't apply here I don't think.
Fingerprinting I am convinced yes that sounds better.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your first question:

No, the method you described is not a standard approach.

The current industry best practices for authentication are set in [NIST Special Publication 800-63B](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html), and notably say not to hash passwords, but to use a key stretching algorithm, such as PBKDF2 or BALLOON. In my research, the key stretching algorithms that are most often suggested by security researchers are PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt, and Argon2.

The entirety of SP 800-63 is relatively easy to read. It might be contradicted by other standards out there, notably PCI DSS.  While I personally believe that PCI and other standards actively decrease security when compared to the NIST standards, you should consult with your company's legal department, as following other standards may reduce liability.

For your follow up question:

A constant value used as a salt is called *pepper*, and reduces the security on a per-password basis.  It is still better than no salt at all, but unless you system is extremely starved for resources to the point where you database can't grow a couple of kilobytes without impacting performance, there is no practical point in having a hardcoded salt rather than a per-password salt.

The point of salt is to prevent an attacker from trivially reversing hashes using a rainbow table.  When using a constant as pepper, an attacker can build a new rainbow table based on that hardcoded value.

Splitting the place where a salt is stored—such as a constant in your application and a constant on the client—does not increase the security of the salt; it merely makes two separate salts.

A couple things about salt:

A salt is not a secret. It should not be stored in weird places, encrypted, or derived from some obscure value. Putting it right next the the result of key stretching/hashing is perfectly fine and is what is used in most standard, secure password verification systems.

A salt should be generated from a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator (csprng), and there should be a unique one per password.  There are only 4 billion IPv4 IP addresses out there, and they tend to clump by region/ISP.

IP addresses are definitely not generated by a csprng, and it's possible that multiple users could have the same IP address, thanks to NAT, and possible that a single user could have multiple IP addresses, thanks to ISPs pooling and randomly assigning IP addresses.  These cases are outside of the user's control.

If you do want to enforce a single IP address to a given user, then store it as an additional field, rather than as part of the authentication. That way, when you realize just how bad of an idea it is, you won't have to rework all of your auth system.

Comment: So building the rainbow table, if I have "pepper" or if I have salt per-password, if the db containing my salt values + hashes or the application containing the pepper + db of hashes is leaked, won't it take just as long to build the rainbow table either way? I understood different salt per entry was to make sure the same data gets hashed to two different values (meaning attackers can spot common patterns to target) but was no more secure than a global constant for a single piece of data.

Comment: Memory size of another field isn't the issue. The issue is if I use uniquely salted hashes, and a new IP address comes up, I need to hash it with all prev salt values to see if it is a duplicate IP. If I use a constant salt (pepper) then I only need to hash once and lookup the hash in the db in linear time. If I use a very slow hashing algorithm to prevent brute force attacks like trying every IP, then that would backfire when I try to lookup the hashed IP in the db wouldn't it?

Comment: If you have pepper, they only have to build 1 rainbow table. If you have a per-password hash, they have to build a rainbow table for every single password... which is exactly what brute forcing is.  (And the solution for brute forcing is to use key stretching algorithms. (not just "slow hashing", but one of the 5 mentioned above.) Many of which default to correctly handling the salt for you, preventing you from making huge mistakes like trying to use IP addresses as part of the salt.)

Comment: Thanks that makes sense on the rainbow table. To be clear the IP address isn't the salt in any case. The IP address is equivalent to a password. It is the secret piece of data I don't want to leak. I will take a look at those algorithms - do they produce a hash-like string i.e. they are a 1->1 irreversible function `$IP_Verifier = bcrypt($IP, $salt)`?

Comment: Since you're using `$`, it's possible that you're using PHP.  Great news: that makes things easier with the functions `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php  (Don't let the name fool you; it provides bcrypt and Argon2 by default, not simple hashing algorithms. Extensions can add PBKDF2 and scrypt, but are beyond the scope of this answer.)

Comment: Right, sorry, @Polygorial... That's a few orders of magnitude, and when we're dealing with hashes, it's the difference between microseconds and milliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

There are some points:

1. IP addresses are already on the HTTP server logs

   You are not hashing nor encrypting them, but they are recorded.
2. You are not exposing IP addresses by default

   Unless you have a mechanism to query your database and expose the information, all IP addresses are protected inside your database.
3. IP addresses are not good for statistics

   There are a couple things that will make your statistics unreliable: dynamic IP, roaming clients, mobile users, and Carrier Grade NAT.

   Dynamic IP users will have their IP changed from time to time, and it may seem like one client is accessing twice but in fact are two different clients that got the same IP allocated.

   Roaming clients are those who connect thru various wireless networks. This will make the same client have distinct IP addresses on your system, and distinct clients having the same IP.

   Mobile users may all have a small pool of external IP addresses being used by the telecom operator. This will look like several hundreds (or thousands) of access by a single client.

   Carrier Grade NAT: on small ISPs, that is common: the ISP have a handful of Class C Networks, and use NAT to allow its clients to access the internet.

You can collect better statistics using tracking cookies, or a long-lived session, or using client fingerprinting.

Answer (score 2):

You might take inspiration from some of the cookie-free and privacy-aware web analytics solutions that have sprung up. These include [Fathom](https://usefathom.com/blog/anonymization), [Plausible](https://plausible.io/data-policy) and [Ackee](https://docs.ackee.electerious.com/#/docs/Anonymization). They all generally attempt to solve the following problem: track whether a user has already visited the site for aggregation purposes, but without storing information on their machine (for ePrivacy Directive reasons), and without storing identifying information on the server (for GDPR reasons).

They generally work by creating a hash of the connecting IP, the site they're connecting to and the user-agent, as well as a rotating salt. Pseudo-code from [Plausible's explainer](https://plausible.io/data-policy#how-we-count-unique-users-without-cookies) looks like:

```
hash(daily_salt + website_domain + ip_address + user_agent)
```

Each of these are used for:

Daily rotating salt

Important for a number of reasons:

- Using a server-generated salt limits the risk of rainbow table attacks, and having it time-limited (e.g. rotating daily) means that even custom rainbow tables would only affect a small subset of data.
- Using a time-limited salt means that even an attacker with full access to the database and server would be unable to check whether a given user has visited the site, assuming the salt has been rotated since.

This comes with the trade-off of only being able to track whether a visitor has accessed the site within the last salt rotation cycle.

IP

Used as a proxy for identifying the individual user. While not perfect (see ThoriumBR's answer), IP addresses do act as a coarse identifier for when exact identification isn't critical.

User-Agent

Used to differentiate different devices coming from the same IP. This alleviates some of the issues with using IP for identification (although not all).

Domain ID

Acts as a salt, to avoid collisions when multiple different sites track visitors using the same database and rotating salt. Mostly used for practical reasons.

---

While some limitations apply to this scheme, it is generally a trade-off between security/privacy and usability. [As described by Plausible](https://plausible.io/data-policy#how-we-count-unique-users-without-cookies) (who admittedly have a vested interest in framing it positively):

> In our testing, using IP addresses to count visitors is remarkably accurate when compared to using a cookie. In some cases it might even be more accurate than using a cookie because some visitors block cookies altogether.
>
> The biggest limitation with this approach is that we cannot do good retention analysis with Plausible. We cannot show stats like New vs Returning visitors because they rely on having a persistent user identifier.
>
> If the same visitor visits your site five times in one day we will show that as one unique visitor. But if the same visitor visits your site on five different days in a month we would show that as five unique visitors.

Comment: In this instance `user_agent` == `$CONST_Client_salt` from my question. The idea of a rotating server salt is clever though. I'd probably need to do once every few days, in which case I need to be sure it takes > 3 days to create a rainbowtable with that period's salt. Therefore a slow hashing algo like bcrypt seems more sensible than the SHA256 they use on their site